# ImportError when trying to install Package Control in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, package-control

I tried installing Package Control in Sublime Text 2. I entered the following install code from the official website into the console:

```
import urllib2,os,hashlib; 
h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; 
pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; 
ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); 
os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; 
urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler()) ); 
by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); 
dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); 
open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; 
print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')`
```

However, the only result I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

I don't understand why `urllib2` isn't there. I checked which version of Python Sublime is using and it's 3.3.3.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.3.3 (default, Dec 19 2013, 14:22:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.24)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using Sublime Text 2 and not 3? Because I'm pretty sure 2.0.2 is built on Python 2.6.5, while 3.0 beta is built on 3.3.3…

Comment: Great catch, @abarnert! I _thought_ it was v2 because - to the best of my knowledge - v3 wasn't even around when I installed it two years ago and I just assumed it would not update to v3 until v3 is a stable release (it's still in beta). Now I just used the installation code for Sublime 3 instead and everything worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I just checked and I have "Stable Channel, Build 3065", which is a 3.0 beta, so apparently 3.0 is considered stable even though it's still beta. (And it certainly seems pretty stable in practice.) I think there are also bleeding-edge and stick-with-2.x channels, but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: Yeah, we use the same version. I haven't noticed any glitches while using it either. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Python 3, and you're following instructions for Python 2.

Among the many differences between the two languages is that Python 3 reorganized `urllib2` and a bunch of related modules into the `urllib` package. In particular, the `urlopen` function, the `ProxyHandler` class, etc. are now in `urllib.request` instead of `urlopen`.

However, you'd probably do better looking for Python 3 instructions than trying to hack up the Python 2 instructions to work.

Especially since, if there *aren't* any Python 3 instructions, there's a decent possibility that the program doesn't work with Python 3 and will just end up leaving unusable garbage in your site-packages or Sublime plugins or something.

Even more so because usually if you're using Python 3 with Sublime Text, you're actually using Sublime Text 3 beta, which has some changes of its own from Sublime Text 2.

Comment: i tweaked the code a bit to make it work `import urllib.request as urllib2`